# Why this Syntax Error on Python 3.8 for Mac

Tags: python, syntax

Check out the screenshot and help this newb with why i'm getting this syntax error with the for loop even though im following the right syntax.

The code :

```
elif choice == 'AVERAGE':
import statistics
lst = []
n = int(input('Enter number of values to calculate mean of: ')
for i in range(0,n):
        ele=int(input())
        lst.append(ele)
```

The Error : Invalid Syntax for the ':' after 'range(0,n)'

Comment: Do not add a picture of the code but the code itself

Comment: In addition what is the error you are getting? (It seems like you have two tabs of indentation instead of one - which would raise a syntax error)

Comment: Kindly share the full snippet of the code, including the error.

Comment: just did ! edited it to be more clear

Comment: You are missing the closing paren in the line above. Change it to `n = int(input('Enter number of values to calculate mean of: '))`

Comment: its fixed now ! i had another error after this where i forgot to use ' for a string, but now its all working, i apologise for the silly error, i just began learning Python 12 days ago.

Comment: The code you posted starts with an `elif` - a guaranteed syntax error. You'll need to post something that we can run and get the same syntax error as you.

Comment: Ah, yes the code is a bit large , but no i've got it figured now, thanks for the eagle vision !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are spacing the items inside the for loop with double `Tab`, the indentation should be either 4 spaces or a single tab.

And you are missing a parenthesis closing in the `n` input line

See the modified code below.

```
elif choice == 'AVERAGE':
    import statistics
    lst = []
    n = int(input('Enter number of values to calculate mean of: '))
    for i in range(0,n):
        ele=int(input())
        lst.append(ele)
```

Comment: That's also still messed up. Best to post something without syntax errors.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem, so should not yet be accepted.

Comment: It's not working because the user hasn't shared the whole code. The code `elif choice == 'AVERAGE'` is from somewhere above as the `choice` variable isn't mentioned in the snippet provided. But the errors in that particular section are solved.

Comment: ...you say *after* fixing the syntax error I highlighted. The answer at the time of my comment was wrong. Seems needlessly argumentative.

Comment: If you remove the first line `elif choice == 'AVERAGE':`, then the remaining code is working fine.

Comment: The block in the elif needs to be indented.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. I was missing the trailing paren , as well as the '' for a string value later in the code. IDLE picks up paren errors but shows them in a very sketchy way (imo) hence i had to come here. A trivial error ,really.